# Domain-Driven Design - Repository Creation

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

*Very* new (and likely confused) to DDD but I followed along after reading some books and tutorials, and want to create a very simple sample project for a friend. I wanted ask for some advice on how to proceed if it's no trouble!

I have a test company that has employees, and employees make sales. The proof of concept was to create/read/update/delete employees and sales that they make. The other need is to come up with statistics for the sales they make (by quarter, by year, by month, by day, as well and i'm sure more will come later). One very special page is going to show statistics across all things - the # of employees at this company, the employee who has made the highest # of sales, the total amount of sales made by quarter, by year, by month, and by day for all employees. Also the goal was to show the best week of the year, and the best day of the week (so if Monday this week made most sales, show that, etc).

My questions if someone could advise me:

1) Can I make a repository for my employees and sales combined? Is that my aggregate root? What about when you have a situation where you need to perform a lot of analysis on data? SQL would be significantly faster in doing this (sums, counts, groups, etc) than trying anything in code, so I'll need a lot of Sql statements to sum up and return the data. Should I create a repository whose sole job is to process data that will be used for reports? Or does this belong in the same repository, even if it would introduce a lot more code? What type of data should be returned? I was thinking of making a "YearlyReport" class and a "weekly report" class or something like that. Bad idea?

2) If somehow down the line I have to add a new repository (let's say for equipment that's in the office) and on that special page above I want to display the # of water coolers, is it acceptable to reference two repositories to get the data (I understand how absurd that sounds to display unrelated data points in a grid, but let's just say it was required). What is a good approach when you're taking subsets of data from disparate things to display onto a combined page?

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> Can I make a repository for my employees and sales combined?

Sure you can, but that would break the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). It doesn't sound like a good idea.

> Is that my aggregate root?

No, the aggregate root is the domain object you can pass to the repository for CRUD operations. An aggregate root is the smallest possible object you can use for CRUD operations on a repository. So if your Employee object has a Roles object and the Employee object is the aggregate root your EmployeeRepository will not be able to work on Roles objects.

> What about when you have a situation where you need to perform a lot of analysis on data? SQL would be significantly faster in doing this (sums, counts, groups, etc) than trying anything in code, so I'll need a lot of Sql statements to sum up and return the data. Should I create a repository whose sole job is to process data that will be used for reports?

That would be a good idea. Leave the calculation to the database where you can and retrieve that calculated data via a ReportRepository.

> Or does this belong in the same repository, even if it would introduce a lot more code? What type of data should be returned? I was thinking of making a "YearlyReport" class and a "weekly report" class or something like that. Bad idea?

Not a bad idea. Just think about how you are going to prevent duplicate code. A YearlyReport is probably not all that different from a WeeklyReport. Perhaps they can both simply be a Report with a different time frame or perhaps they can inherit from the same base class.

> If somehow down the line I have to add a new repository (let's say for equipment that's in the office) and on that special page above I want to display the # of water coolers, is it acceptable to reference two repositories to get the data (I understand how absurd that sounds to display unrelated data points in a grid, but let's just say it was required).

Design wise I see no problem in using multiple repositories to formulate an answer. It might just not perform very well.

> What is a good approach when you're taking subsets of data from disparate things to display onto a combined page?

You would have to abstract those things inside your domain model if you would not know a priori what they would be.